# UWP 10 C# HttpResponseMessage task freezes

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I couldn't find from search anyone having similar issues so:

I'm trying to get XML from server with HttpClient, but my UI freezes weirdly at line "task.Wait()". This is the code:

```
public void register() {
    String data = "register=" + (accountName) + "&email0=" +
                (email) + "&email1=" + (otherEmail);
    var task = MakeRequest(data);
    task.Wait();                  //freezes here
    var response = task.Result;
    String resultstring = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}

private static async Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage> MakeRequest(String data)
{
     var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
     System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage responseMessage=null;
     try
     {
         responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(server, content);
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         responseMessage.ReasonPhrase = string.Format("RestHttpClient.SendRequest failed: {0}", ex);
     }
        return responseMessage;
 }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not freezing weirdly at all - it's freezing entirely reasonably.

You're calling `task.Wait()`, which stops your UI thread from doing any more work until that task has completed. However, that task itself needs to get back to the UI thread when the task returned by `httpClient.PostAsync` completes, in order to continue with the rest of your async method.

Basically, you shouldn't use `Task.Wait()` or `Task.Result` unless you know *for sure* that the task itself won't be blocked waiting to continue on the thread you're currently executing on.

Ideally, your `register` method (which should be `Register` to follow .NET naming conventions) should be asynchronous as well, so you can await the task returned by `MakeRequest`.

Additionally, you should probably change the way `MakeRequest` awaits the task - as the rest of that method doesn't *really* need to run on the UI thread, you can use:

```
responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(server, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Finally, this line:

```
responseMessage.ReasonPhrase = string.Format("RestHttpClient.SendRequest failed: {0}", ex);
```

... will throw a `NullReferenceException` if it ever executes. If an exception is thrown, `responseMessage` will still be null.

Answer (score 0):

Answer of Jon Skeet solved my problem, and here is the working code, if some other beginner is having same problems.

```
public async void Register{
        String data = "register=" + (accountName) + "&email0=" +
            (email) + "&email1=" + (otherEmail);
        var task = await MakeRequest(data);
        String resultstring = taskContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}

private static async Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage> MakeRequest(String data)
{
    var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    return await httpClient.PostAsync(server, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your final code still has several problems, namely `async void` and the use of `Task<T>.Result`. Please read my [MSDN article on `async` best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx); it should help you out.